# How to get a list of timestamps for the past 7 days in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a list of timestamps from current_timestamp to current_timestamp - interval 'variable_no_of_days' day but I am not sure how to do this.

I need to either create a function that takes a variable i.e. how many no. of days before till which it should get the timestamps and generates this list on which I can create a view to be able to use it in a query.

Eg : if i want timestamps from now to 3 days before I`ll do

```
select current_timestamp - interval '3' day, current_timestamp - interval '2' day, current_timestamp - interval '1' day, current_timestamp - interval '0' day
```

which gives me

```
6/20/2015 12:15:53 PM   6/21/2015 12:15:53 PM   6/22/2015 12:15:53 PM   6/23/2015 12:15:53 PM
```

But how can I make it a function so that I can give any number of days and get a list.

I saw a query like this but I don`t see a adddatetime function where I can do the same for timestamp and the where clause would work coz right now it works for dates for the current where clause in the query posted below it shows data like

```
323031352d30362d3231
323031352d30362d3232
323031352d30362d3233
```

.

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between current_timestamp - interval '3' day and current_timestamp
```

Comment: can you use an union?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dates (n_date TIMESTAMP);

/* loop n times */
insert into dates select current_timestamp - interval '5' day;

select n_date from dates;
```

Sorry I did not provide the loop code but I don't have the right MySQL Version

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the number of days in a variable or a subquery

**SUGGESTION #1 : User-defined Variable**

```
SET @daysback = 3;
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between
current_timestamp - interval @daysback day and current_timestamp;
```

**SUGGESTION #2 : Subquery**

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v,
 (select 3 daysback) w
where selected_date between
current_timestamp - interval daysback day and current_timestamp;
```

## Give it a Try !!!